# WiX COM+ error code

Tags: wix, com+

I'm trying to register COM+ with WiX. I get the following error. Where can I find the meaning of error code -2146368486?

```
RegisterComPlusAssemblies: DLL: <file name>
ComPlusInstallExecute:  ErrorInfo: Name='<file name>', ErrorCode='-2146368486', MajorRef='<name>', MinorRef='<invalid>'
ComPlusInstallExecute:  ErrorInfo: Name='<name>', ErrorCode='-2146368486', MajorRef='<guid>', MinorRef='<invalid>'
ComPlusInstallExecute:  ErrorInfo: Name='<name>', ErrorCode='-2146368486', MajorRef='<guid>', MinorRef='<invalid>'
ComPlusInstallExecute:  Error 0x80110401: Failed to install components
ComPlusInstallExecute:  Error 0x80110401: Failed to register native assembly
ComPlusInstallExecute:  Error 0x80110401: Failed to register assembly, key: <assembly>
ComPlusInstallExecute:  Error 0x80110401: Failed to register assemblies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the calculator, type the number, switch to hex:

```
FFFFFFFF8011041A
```

drop the higher part, prepend "0x":

```
0x8011041A
```

and Google it:
http://www.google.pl/#hl=pl&source=hp&q=0x8011041A